# Boost logger maximum collector size

Tags: c++, logging, boost

I am using BOOST for my Logger API. I have a scenario when the maximum size of collector is reached it should stop logging. but currently the application is crashing.

Example: maximum size of collector = 10MB and Maximum file size =4MB so it generates two files with size 4MB each and 1 with 2MB and the application should stop but its crashing here.

Code is given below:

```
sink = boost::make_shared<file_sink>(keywords::file_name = file_name,
    keywords::rotation_size = m_maxLogFileSize,
    keywords::open_mode = std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::app,
    keywords::auto_flush = true
    );

try{
    sink->locked_backend()->set_file_collector(sinks::file::make_collector(keywords::target = m_dirLocation, keywords::max_size = 1 * 1024));// m_maxLogFileSize));
    //sink->locked_backend()->set_file_collector(sinks::file::make_collector(keywords::target = m_dirLocation, keywords::max_size = 10 * 1024 *1024, keywords::min_free_space = 1024));
}
catch (exception e)
{
    std::cout << "Maximum size reached in collector" << std::endl;
}

sink->set_formatter(
                        expr::stream
                        << expr::format_date_time< boost::posix_time::ptime >("TimeStamp", m_timeFormat) << m_logSeparator
                        << "[" << expr::attr< boost::log::trivial::severity_level >("Severity") << "]" << m_logSeparator << "  "
                        << expr::attr< boost::thread::id >("ThreadID") << m_logSeparator << "  "
                        << expr::attr<std::string>("FileName") << ""
                        << ":" << expr::attr<int>("Line") << m_logSeparator << "  "
                        << expr::attr<std::string>("Function") << m_logSeparator << "  "
                        << expr::xml_decor[expr::stream << expr::smessage]
                    );

sink->locked_backend()->scan_for_files();
sink->locked_backend()->auto_flush(true);

// Add the sink to the core
logging::core::get()->add_sink(sink);
```

Comment: I am not criticizing your approach, but I guess the standard way is to do file rotation ([see doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/sink_backends.html)) which means that the chance of getting help here is not that big.  In most cases, stop logging is far worse than losing old logs.  Still, it would be nice to have this fixed.  Maybe better report this to [boost](www.boost.org/development/bugs.html)

Comment: One question: is it crashing when calling set_file_collector or when the collector becomes full? It was not clear what the "crashing here" meant.

Comment: It is crashing when the collector becomes full....